# Adding UI Components to a Blackberry ListField

Tags: blackberry

I am building a chat application for BlackBerry 4.6.0, and want to create a Contacts screen. This screen will list your active and inactive contacts. In order to do this I am trying to use a ListField, and it's associated ListFieldCallback.

My question is if it is possible to draw normal Ui components (like an VerticalFieldManager, CheckboxField, RadioButtonFields, etc) in each of my list items.

I see that the drawListRow method that should be overridden to draw a list item only provides a Graphics object. If at all possible I would rather not have to draw all the components I want manually using it (would be a major time drain!). Isn't there a way that I could get a fieldManager to use the Graphics object to draw itself with the appropriate x/y and width/height values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One does not normally add UI objects to a list since if the list has many items the overhead would quickly consume available resources. The application is responsible for rendering the list times in a ListFieldCallback. The ListField, designed this way, can efficiently display all contacts, or all messages even on a device without much memeory.

If your applicatin is to display a small number of items then instead of the ListField use a UI element that extends Manager.

Comment: Thanks. Not the answer I had hoped for, but that does make sense.